# Mobile site navigation - Burger menu or not?

Tags: layout, design, responsive-design

Can anyone share some stats on the pros and cons of both using a burger menu (standard drop down or pop out) Vs a simplified navigation for mobile.

Examples of great navigation can be found here:

http://www.yapstone.com/

http://newrelic.com/ - nice sections for products on mobile

Is there a way of turning this into a poll on here?

Comment: How would a poll help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should design both, why not? I think a navigation that works without burger menu is better for visibility, but sometimes it's unavoidable on mobile platforms.